# RedirectToAction problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirecttoaction

I have a Controller: AdminPageController, in which I have the following actions: Index, Create, Save

My save action is as follows:

```
public ActionResult Save(string[] inputs, int columnsCount)
{
.....
    return  RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

I can see that the debugger passes throug the redurectToAction , but the index is not displayed.  I can see that the routing is written as follows:

```
http://localhost:55405/AdminPage/Create#
```

What is wrong and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this utility displays the route data pulled from the request of the current request in the address bar. So you can type in various URLs in the address bar to see which route matches.
http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx

Comment: Despite going through actionresult Index, I can see that there is no chnage in the navigation bar.  Why? Is it because i`m using ajax to send the data? I can`t figure out why it`s not pointing to AdminPage/Index even after passing through that actionresult

Comment: If you are using ajax ,there will be no change in the url because Ajax asynchronous postback take place